# Read and write to a Opc DA server in python

Tags: python, opc-da, open-opc

I'm trying to read and write in a Opc Da server that run on localhost with 11159 port and server id 'BR.OPC.Server_3.0_V1.14.2'.
This is my code:

```
import OpenOPC
import pywintypes

pywintypes.datetime = pywintypes.TimeType
opc=OpenOPC.open_client('localhost',11159)
```

I tryed also with the server id but always I get 'cannot connect .....' error.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you start an instance of the OpenOpc Service? see documentation https://github.com/iterativ/openopc2